# How can I use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to get the nth prime?

Tags: algorithm, math

I've written a function, `sieve(n)`, that uses the Sieve of Eratosthenes to return an array of all primes up to `n`.

```
sieve(25) # ==> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
```

The source for this function can be read [here](http://pastebin.ca/2969835).

I want to refactor this now so that `sieve(n)` will return the `n`th prime. I'm just not sure about how I'd do that. I don't want to write an entirely new more elaborate function, so it seems like the best method is to figure out what value the sieve should count up to.

For example, if I ask for the 27th prime, the sieve's initial list of integers should be 2 up to *(something I know the 27th prime isn't greater than)*. But is there a simple way to work out what that value is?

I researched this question and found [this Quora post](http://www.quora.com/What-are-good-ways-to-find-nth-prime-number-in-the-fastest-way/answer/Jason-Martin) which said that the nth prime must be between `n*Math.log(n) + n*(Math.log(Math.log(n))-1)` and `n*Math.log(n) + n*Math.log(Math.log(n))` (where `Math.log` is Ruby for the natural logarithm), but simply making `list` an array of numbers between those two figures makes the sieve yield weird values, like `56` for the 15th prime (56 is not prime and the answer should be 47).

As you can guess, I'm totally out of my element here. If someone could offer me some advice I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You shouldn't ask it to generate prime numbers *between* anything. The whole algorithm is built around the knowledge that it has found all primes before a certain point before moving on. You need to ask it to find primes from 1 and up to the upper bound.

Comment: Would the following approach be an acceptable solution? Use the upper bound you mention in your question (however I wasn't aware of that and have no idea why it is correct) to generate all primes smaller than the bound and return the `n-th` element of the list.

Comment: @Codor That's what I thought would work, but it has some very weird results that I don't understand. If I set my initial list to 2 to the upper bound, I get primes for a while, and then just a steady count -- 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, etc. It's bizarre.

Comment: Instead of listing primes between those bounds, use your sieving function to compute the primes less than the upper bound, then count to the desired prime. If you get non-primes, then your sieving function is incorrect.

Comment: @GreenTriangle This is not what I meant; I meant leaving the sieve of Erathostenes as it is, but use the upper bound as an argument for it (i.e. generate all primes from zero up to the bound) and then return the desired entry from the result of the sieve of Erathosthenes.

Comment: @Codor Oh, my mistake. I see what you mean now and you're completely right, a clever solution. Thanks for your input, your idea serves really nicely.

Answer (score 5):

The sieve of Eratosthenes always has to start from the beginning; you can't sieve in some arbitrary interval since you'd loose all smaller primes. So you don't have to care for a lower bound, only for an upper bound. Which you gave, and which [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) confirms:

*p<sub>n</sub>* < *n* ln (*n* ln *n*) for *n* ≥ 6

So simply take that bound, plug in your *n* and iterate till you have found *n* primes. Your sieve will usually be a bit too big, but not too much if the bound is reasonably tight, which I expect to be the case.

See [here](http://ideone.com/Uu0cY2) for a table of that bound or [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20%7Bn*ln%28n*ln%28n%29%29%2CPrime[floor%28n%29]%7D%2C%7Bn%2C2%2C100%7D) for a plot. By the way, the code creating the table is doing the same thing. I wanted at least 500 entries, so I computed

```py
n = 500
lst = list(range(2, ceil(n*log(n*log(n)))))
ps = []
while lst:
    p = lst[0] # next prime
    ps.append(p)
    lst = [i for i in lst if i % p != 0]
```

and got a bit over 500 primes out of it, for which I then could show you how the computed bound compares to the actual value.

Comment: if you see `%` in the code; it is not Sieve of Eratosthenes. Here's a [simple implementation in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33014445/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, well, I'm lazy. Of course it would be more in the spirit of the pen-and-paper version of the algorithm to have a boolean list and iterate over that in steps. But having only the non-crossed-out numbers makes it easier to find the next prime, avoiding one line of code and up to two levels of indentation. At some computational cost, sure.

Comment: your modulo-based algorithm has nothing to do with the sieve algorithm e.g., the former has different (much worse) time complexity.