# First 100 prime numbers

Tags: python, primes

I know there are a number of ways to find the first 100 prime numbers but please help me in my approach. I find the value of `count` to be increasing but for some reason the `while` loop condition doesn't apply:

```
count = 0

while(count <= 20):
    for i in range(2, 20):
        for j in range(2, i):
            if i < j:
                print("The number",i,"is prime")
            elif i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            print("The number",i,"is prime")
            count = count + 1
            print(count)
```

Comment: Also `while(count <= 20):` is generally written as `while count <= 20:`

Comment: @JonSurrell: don't change the question if it invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find the first `n` prime numbers:

```
def primes_upto(limit):
    prime = [True] * limit
    for n in range(2, limit):
        if prime[n]:
            yield n # n is a prime
            for c in range(n*n, limit, n):
                prime[c] = False # mark composites
```

To get the first 100 primes:

```
>>> list(primes_upto(542))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, ... ,
 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541]
```

To find the first `n` primes, you could [estimate n-th prime (to pass the upper bound as the limit)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1257/1665) or use [an infinite prime number generator](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117119-sieve-of-eratosthenes/) and get as many numbers as you need e.g., using `list(itertools.islice(gen, 100))`.

Comment: The OP is asking for help with their code, not for an improved prime finder/generator.

Comment: @JonSurrell it answers the question in the title. 95+% percent of visitors are from web-search engines. If OP had asked how to write a while loop; the answer would be different.

Comment: You are correct that the _title_ does not accurately reflect the content of the question. If the OP had read and understood [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the title would surely be different. But the _title_ is not the _question_, and I disagree that we should ignore the question the OP asks and answer what we decide the title says. Perhaps a better course of action is to suggest and edit to the title.

Comment: Thanks Jon! I shall post it properly the next time. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: @jfs hey , thanks for your answer just a quick question, why the second for loop started from n*n ?? still unclear fro me now

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi because composites less than `n*n` that are divided by `n` are marked earlier already. Follow the first link and look at the animation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more simpler code. We have looped all the numbers from 0 to the number until we have printed 100 prime numbers.

```
n=0
i=0
while n<100:
    i+=1
    count=1
    for j in range(2,i):
        if i%j==0:
            count=0
            break
    
    if count==1:
        print(i,end=' ')
        n+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If one is looking for a mix of efficiency and simple code, Numpy is worth a try. With some fancy indexing, the following code does the job of implementing the sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
import numpy as np

ns = np.array(range(2,N))
primes = []
last_prime=2
while last_prime:
    primes.append(last_prime)
    ns = ns[ns%last_prime != 0]
    last_prime = ns[0] if len(ns) > 0 else None
print(primes[:100])
```

Then just adjust N until you do have 100 primes. A good first guess is something in the order of 100*log(100) ~ 460 (coming from the prime number theorem). This will give 88 primes. Increasing N to the value of 600, you will have enough primes.

Answer (score 0):

```
prime_count=0
n=1
while(True):
    count=0
    i=2
    n+=1
    while(i<=n):
        if(n==i):
            print(n)
            prime_count+=1
        elif(n%i==0):
            break
        i+=1
    if(prime_count==100):
        break
```

Comment: This code could really use an explanation!

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Okay Thanks for Advice,From Next Time Will Keep In Mind

Answer (score 0):

```
i=1
n=2
prime_list=[]
while(i<100):
    prime=True
    for j in range(2,n//2+1):
        if n%j==0:
            prime=False
    if(prime==True):
        prime_list.append(n)
        i=i+1
    n=n+1
```

Comment: You need to explain why the code in your answer is better than the other examples, otherwise no one will know why they should use this and not the others.