# Finding nth prime using Seive of Eratosthens

Tags: java, algorithm, math, primes

I am using Seive of Eratosthenes to calculate 1,000,001th prime number, however, I am unable to calculate the upperbound to use Seive. My function :

```
public static void Seive(int num){
    BitSet primes = new BitSet();

    for(int i=2; i<=num; i++){
        if(!primes.get(i)){
            for(int j=i+i; j<=num; j+=i){
                primes.set(j);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=2; i<=num; i++){
        if(!primes.get(i))
            System.out.print(i + " ");
    }       

}
```

Calculates the primes from 2 to num, but what if I don't know the range but am interested in finding the nth number.

Comment: Just a note, you can watch a Youtube video by Numberphile about prime numbers, the `n`th prime is approximately equal to `n*ln(n)`.

Comment: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/jaroma03200545640.pdf

Comment: just a small detail, but the sieve code will run considerably faster if you replace `i+i` with `i*i`. (All the composite numbers less than `i*i` will already have been eliminated from the sieve, so there's no need to visit them again.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to get the nth prime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540420/how-can-i-use-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-to-get-the-nth-prime)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A corollary to the prime number theorem states that, for *n* > 5, the *n*th prime is between *n* log *n* and *n* (log *n* + log log *n*) with logarithms to base *e*. Thus, an easy way to find the first *n* primes is to sieve to the upper bound then discard primes beyond the *n*th.

Answer (score 1):

That's the point in [Project Euler - Problem 7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7) that I suspect your working on.  It's designed in such a way as to make it hard to use the [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). 
This problem is small enough to use a [brute force method](https://github.com/rossdrew/programmingproblems/blob/master/src/com/rox/prob/euler/Problem7.java) or instead of standard brute force division, store your primes and brute force using them.

Comment: PE7 is to find 10,001th prime, mine is to find 1,000,0001th :-D

Comment: same concept applies.  It's hard to use an upper bound based algorithm who's required bounds aren't known

Comment: storing primes will require the upper bound too, how would i know the list of primes is finished so that i can brute force?

Comment: yes, the number of primes you are looking for.  It's not an unknown upper bound. The first few can be hard coded or generated.  Everytime you use primes to figure out the next, you add it to the list and use it from then on

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem). A good approximation for the upper bound would be `n * ln(n)`(here the base **does** matter).